# I just need to break a loop on a specific page (wordpress/woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Would anyone care to help me disable the loop on a WooCommerce (Wordpress plugin) shop page?

I've used shortcodes to fill the page with the product categories that I need, so now I need to stop WooCommerce from displaying anything underneath my content (WooCommerce is loading the products from the loop but I don't want it to).

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
```

^ Somewhere in there I need to implement if(is_shop()) to display nothing on the /shop page, and then elseif to display the above code so that the subcategory pages and product archives don't break.

I would be very grateful for any help...

Comment: Get the id of the page, and create a condition based on that.

Comment: It doesn't display a page ID as it pulls the content for the shop and category pages from product-archive.php. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How to remove the sort order, product/category loop, and pagination from the shop page, so as to implement your own content using only shortcodes via the page editor.

product-archive.php:

```
<?php if ( !is_shop() ) : ?>
    <?php
    /**
    * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
    * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
    */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
    ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
        <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    <?php
    /**
    * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
    */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that you're not on a shop page using `is_shop()`. See the [WooCommerce Docs on Conditional Tags](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/) for more info.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() && !is_shop() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

I didn't completely understand whether or not you're okay with completely getting rid of the posted code on the shop page...but if you are, you can wrap the entire thing in a conditional:

```
<?php if ( !is_shop() ) : ?>
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is not good, because it will halt when it `is_shop()` Instead of this, he need to add a condition outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: Why? He said he doesn't want it to return any WC content when on the shop page. Perhaps I misunderstood...in which case I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Oh, i see, you are right. I missunderstood what you did.

Comment: This worked! It still displays the "Sort Order" drop-down and pagination links below my content. I can hide them with CSS though if need be?

Comment: Ummm...yeah, should be able to, assuming you can target them on that page specifically. If you're able to hide of ALL of the above code you posted, you could alternatively write a big conditional that wraps the entire set of functions.

Comment: Ah yeah on second thought it doesn't produce a page ID because it pulls the content from product-archive.php so the CSS solution won't work. 

Sadly I'm far too n00b to "write a big conditional".

Comment: Updated the answer with the big conditional.